# Does SMTP accept "friendly" address in FROM line (in particular Exchange)

Tags: smtp

I have an application server sending mails with SMTP, and this application generates a FROM line that contains a "friendly address" that seems to be refused by Exchange, of the form:

MAIL FROM: "Francois Barriere"<francois.barriere@mydomain.com>

The server (Exchange, but I don't know the version) returns an error. I can reproduce the problem using telnet.
If I change for the following FROM line, the address is accepted:

MAIL FROM: <francois.barriere@mydomain.com>

So it seems the first "friendly address" part between the double quotes is the problem. I haven't found any reference to this address format in the RFC...

Is this format supported by SMTP in general? What is the support status of this in Exchange?

Thanks,

François.

Comment: If I was a mail server, I'd toss that too. Seriously, a FROM without a local-part @ domain isn't a valid, period.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. The last part of the address was not shown because of the HTML entities... I have edited the question to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Both the two examples you give are invalid.

```
MAIL FROM: "Francois Barriere"<francois.barriere@example.com>
```

is invalid and I would expect most servers to reject it.

```
MAIL FROM: <francois.barriere@example.com>
```

is also invalid, but most servers accept it. I have however been rejecting it for years, since rejecting this invalid format got rid of a lot of spam.

```
MAIL FROM:<francois.barriere@example.com>
```

is valid. Notice that no characters are permitted between the `:` and the `<` characters.

```
MAIL FROM:<"francois.barriere"@example.com>
```

is also valid, but it should not be used. Quoting the relevant RFC:

> the sending system SHOULD transmit the
>      form that uses the minimum quoting possible.